# Setting Up Central Database from a few databases

Tags: sql-server, database, data-warehouse, database-replication

I have a few databases which I want to replicate in a central database.

Just wondering what's the best option so that I can get the data updated on a daily basis. Is it database replication I need to look at ?

For example :

In Server_A, I have 2 databases running on SQL Server 2008 R2
In Server_B, I have 1 database running on SQL Server 2012
In Server_C, I have 1 database running on SQL Server 2005

All the databases above needs to be consolidated to Server_Master running SQL Server 2012.

Do you think is possible ?

Thanks .......

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can use SQL Server Integration Services to do daily dumps from databases on different servers and consolidate them into one or more databases on server_master.

Take a look at the [answer 25867 on dba stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25867/moving-data-from-one-db-to-another-using-ssis) and [a tutorial on Microsoft's site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170419.aspx).

Comment: How we should do the daily update ? Is it full or incremental ? I think SSIS can't provide such option unless we script each table.

Comment: You are correct - with SSIS you would have to script each table. The other option is to create differential backup on a nightly basis and attempt to restore it on server_master.

Comment: I read about database replication. Probably way to go... just I haven't done it before and try to get more information about it.

Comment: Replication might help with near-real time flow of data but not a scheduled daily dump of data. Certainly it's worth a look. Do read through [deprecation warning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143323.aspx) that may impact your daily data loads from 2005 and 2008 R2